# Which type of ANOVA to use?

Tags: anova, biostatistics, growth-model

[image]I would like to know which kind of ANOVA should I use if I'm interested only in the effect of different treatments in growing plants.

The experimental design is as follows: each week for 7 weeks, 4 plants per treatment (there were 4 treatments) were measured for their height. Each week 4 different plants were used for taking the measures and none of them were measured more than once.

Comment: Do you expect any kind of change over time, or are the measurements over the weeks just repetitions of the experiment?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i expect the plants to grow and change over the weeks.

Comment: Well, in that case you could either run an anova with time as a categorical variable, or you could make additional assumptions (e.g. linear change) and use a more powerful regression model. Do you maybe have an idea of the kind of change you expect? Perhaps you could include a graph

Comment: I have added a graph each color is a different treatment, each point represents the mean and the bars the standard deviation. Im interested in the overall treatment effect and not comparing each time point, so im a little confused.

Comment: If you're interested in an overall effect, you should determine what that is: A difference in slopes (perhaps for a logarithmic curve), a difference in final size, or something else.

Comment: To add to @FransRodenburg's good ideas:  look into repeated-measures aka mixed aka random-effects aka multi-level models.